# Scopes & Mask Tabs disappeared from UV/Viewer screen

Tags: interface

Any idea how this could have happened?  I have my keyboard connected to 2 computers (via a/b switch) and occasionally type a key sequence into Blender that is meant for the other computer.  I have no idea what I might have typed to remove those tabs and no clue how to get them back.  I'm doing some color correction and really need my scopes back.  BTW, when I open a new Blender session the tabs are missing.  When I open a backup copy of my color correction, the tabs are there (but I would have to trash all my changes to get back to where I left off.)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** Scopes disappear in Edit Mode. Switch back to Object mode in 3D Viewport.

I figured it out.  I looked in space_image.py and found the following code.

class ImageScopesPanel:
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
sima = context.space_data
if not (sima and sima.image):
return False
# scopes are not updated in paint modes, hide
if sima.mode == 'PAINT':
return False
ob = context.active_object
if ob and ob.mode in {'TEXTURE_PAINT', 'EDIT'}:
return False
return True

I could not quickly figure out the meaning of each of the variables, but decided to take a look at what could turn off the "scopes" tab.  As soon as I turned the "3D View" from "Edit Mode" to "Object Mode", the "Scopes" tab re-appeared on the "UV/Image Editor".